# p5.jsを利用した画像の読み込みと貼り付けに関する質問

Tags: javascript, processing

p5.jsを使って画像の読み込みと貼り付けをしようと思ったのですが、失敗してしまいます。
原因がわかりません。どなたかのご回答をお待ちしております。

### 環境

・PC：mac
・ブラウザ：chrome
・ソースはダウンロードせず、p5.min.jsを外部から読み込んで使用しています。
・サンプルとなる画像は同じディレクトリ内にあります。

### コード

```js
let img;
function preload() {
    img = loadImage("sample.jpg");   // <-- 
}
function setup(){
    let canvas = createCanvas(600, 600);
    canvas.parent('canvas');
    fill(240);
    noStroke();
    background('#002B40');
    // 画像を貼り付け
    image(img, 100, 100);    // <--
    text("あ", 100, 100);
}

function draw(){
    textSize(32);
    text("ああああ", 300, 300);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のいずれかに該当する場合は動作しません。
確認してみてください。

- htmlファイルに`id="canvas"`が存在しない
  公式リファレンスにある[parent()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/parent)のExampleサンプルコードにあるコメントを参照
- [ローカルサーバ](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server)を立てずに`index.html`をローカルファイルとしてChromeで開いている

pythonでローカルサーバを立て、下記の`index.html`を配置して正しく動作することを確認しました。
※質問文のコードは変更せず、`sketch.js`として`index.html`と同一階層に保存しています。

#### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>hoge fuga</p>
    <div id="canvass"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ローカルサーバを立てると動きました　ご回答ありがとうございます！